# How to create a query to check which sub-String (from DB) is contained in a given String?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to write a query, which will compare the country phone code from one table with the full phone number from another table and will output the appropriate country name.

I was playing playing a bit with the conditional query, but I don't know how to bite it.

My DB contains two tables:

tblCall

```
   CallID   |   Caller      | 
____________________________
     1      | +4411111111  |
     2      | +4911111111  |
```

tblCode

```
 CodeID     |   Code   |  Country   | 
_____________________________________
     1      | +44      |   UK       |
     2      | +49      |   Germany  |
```

So I need a query which will check if the code is included in the phone number and will print out the appropriate country name, like this:

```
CallID      |   Caller     | Country
______________________________________
     1      | +4411111111  |   UK
     2      | +4911111111  |  Germany
```

Comment: Show us the query(ies) you have tried

Comment: Add some 1 digit and 3 digit country codes too. https://www.countrycode.org/ For example Usa, Canada and Botswana.

Comment: *So I need a query* -> I suggest that you write one then.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't expect anybody to post up a ready code for me, but some directions of what to use. I didn't post up a code, because what I've tried didn't even take me close to the desired output. I will learn the lesson though and the next time I will include of what I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `join`.  If the code is always three characters, you can use a comparison such as:

```
select ca.*, co.country
from tblCall ca left join
     tblCountry co
     on left(ca.caller, 3) = co.code;
```

If it is variable, then `like`:

```
select ca.*, co.country
from tblCall ca left join
     tblCountry co
     on ca.caller like concat(co.code, '%')
```

Comment: Instead of `3`, use `LENGTH(co.code)` -- This makes it more generic.